# Do I need to correct for multiple testing if I perform one mediation model with 3 parallel mediators?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, mediation, false-discovery-rate

I am performing a mediation model with 3 parallel mediators, 1 independent variable and 1 dependent variable. My question is: is this considered a unique analysis, or should I control for multiple comparisons (since a mediation analysis basically calculate different correlations)?

Thank you very much!

Alessandra

Answer (score 1):

You never *need* to correct for multiple comparisons.  You decide whether (and how) to correct for multiple comparisons based on how you view the necessity and desirability of controlling type I error at the expense of type II error.

No decision here is right or wrong; you have to be able to justify your decision.

Comment: You are right, then I will be clearer. If I reject a null hypothesis I want to know that I do it with a 5% probability of having a false positive (a 5% probability of finding the observed, or more extreme results when the null hypothesis is true). So, if I use a significance threshold of 0.05 to interpret my mediation results, will the probability that I did a Type I error be 5%, or it will actually be more? I am confused because in the mediation you test a single model, but you have many p-values in practice as an output. But, for example, if I performed 3 ANOVAs I would correct for sure.

Comment: Which null are you testing? What is your criterion for significant mediation? (Personally, I wouldn't even look at the significance, I'd look at the effect size).

Comment: The most common procedure is not to correct for multiple tests.